# Weight of polynomial over finite field

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, coding-theory

For $\alpha \in F_{p}$, $\alpha \ne 0$, the polynomial $f(x) = (x+\alpha)^k$ has weight $k+1$, when $k < p$ (the weight is number of non-zero coefficients). This is since both $\binom{k}{i}$ and $\alpha^i$ are $\not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ for $0 \le i \le p-1$ .
Thus all $k+1$ coefficients of $f$ are non-zero (for the next possible exponent, $p$, we have $(x+\alpha)^p = x^p + \alpha^p$ which has weight $2$).

What also seems to be true is that if we look at $(x+\alpha)^k \cdot g(x)$,and keep the degree of $g$ small (i.e. $\le p-k-1$ so that the product has degree $<p$) then the weight of  $(x+\alpha)^k \cdot g(x)$ is *at least* k+1.

Can anyone point me to a proof of this (if it's true)?

Answer (score 1):

Because $f(x)$ and $f(-\alpha x)$ have the same weight we can, without loss of generality, assume that $\alpha=-1$. In that case you are looking at "classical" repeated-root cyclic codes of length $p$ over $\Bbb{F}_p$ generated by $(x-1)^k$. Your claim is equivalent to stating that such codes are MDS. This is known to be the case. You will probably benefit from a study of

- Karl-Heinz Zimmermann, "On generalizations of repeated-root cyclic codes" from March 1996 issue of IEEE Transactions on Information Theory.

He attributes this result independently to Berman ('67) and Assmus & Mattson ('69).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.   Before I go off trying to prove anything, do you know if they are, in fact, known to be MDS? The pointers have lead me to some "recent" work of Simeon Ball etc. and before I delve too deep into those papers, it would be nice to know what I'm getting myself into.

Answer (score 0):

What about $p=5$ with $k=1$ or $k=2$?  Try $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=x-1$, or $f(x)=(x+1)^2$, and $g(x)=(x-1)^2$.

Comment: There was a, now corrected, typo in the original.  I wanted the resulting weight to be >= k+1, not = k + 1.  Dan